# Apache Atlas: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 21000: Connection refused

Tags: maven, apache-atlas

I'm trying to run apache atlas on my local. There are several problem I have faced to.
First, for clearance of how I have build the apache atlas I will describe the steps:

1. git clone https://github.com/apache/atlas
2. cd atlas
3. mvn clean install -DskipTests -X
4. mvn clean package -Pdist -DskipTests

It has been built without any error. Here is the project structure:

```
.
├── 3party-licenses
│   ├── Antlr-LICENSE
│   ├── Respond-LICENSE
│   ├── animate-LICENSE
│   ├── backgrid-columnmanager-LICENSE
│   ├── bootstrap-daterangepicker-LICENSE
│   ├── bootstrap-sidebar-LICENSE
│   ├── es5-shim-LICENSE
│   ├── google-fonts-LICENSE
│   ├── handlebars-LICENSE
│   ├── hbs-LICENSE
│   ├── jQuery-QueryBuilder-LICENSE
│   ├── jQuery-ui-LICENSE
│   ├── janusgraph-LICENSE
│   ├── jquery-placeholder-LICENSE
│   ├── mock-LICENSE
│   ├── normalize.css-LICENSE
│   ├── platform-LICENSE
│   ├── pnotify-LICENSE
│   ├── require-handlebars-plugin-LICENSE
│   ├── swagger-ui-LECENSE
│   └── titan-LICENSE
├── DISCLAIMER.txt
├── LICENSE
├── NOTICE
├── README.txt
├── addons
│   ├── falcon-bridge
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── falcon-bridge-shim
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── hbase-bridge
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── hbase-bridge-shim
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── hbase-testing-util
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── hdfs-model
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   └── target
│   ├── hive-bridge
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── hive-bridge-shim
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── impala-bridge
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── impala-bridge-shim
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── impala-hook-api
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── kafka-bridge
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── 0000-Area0
│   │   ├── 1000-Hadoop
│   │   ├── 2000-RDBMS
│   │   ├── 3000-Cloud
│   │   └── 4000-MachineLearning
│   ├── sqoop-bridge
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── sqoop-bridge-shim
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── storm-bridge
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   └── storm-bridge-shim
│       ├── pom.xml
│       ├── src
│       └── target
├── atlas-examples
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── sample-app
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   └── target
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       └── rat.txt
├── authorization
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   └── test
│   └── target
│       ├── atlas-authorization-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       ├── classes
│       ├── generated-sources
│       ├── generated-test-sources
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       ├── maven-status
│       ├── rat.txt
│       └── test-classes
├── build-tools
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   └── target
│       ├── atlas-buildtools-1.0.jar
│       ├── classes
│       └── maven-archiver
├── client
│   ├── client-v1
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── client-v2
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   └── target
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       └── rat.txt
├── common
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   └── test
│   └── target
│       ├── atlas-common-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
│       ├── atlas-common-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       ├── classes
│       ├── generated-sources
│       ├── generated-test-sources
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       ├── maven-status
│       ├── rat.txt
│       └── test-classes
├── dashboardv2
│   ├── gruntfile.js
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── ieerror.html
│   │   ├── img
│   │   ├── index.html.tpl
│   │   ├── js
│   │   └── migration-status.html.tpl
│   └── target
│       ├── atlas-dashboardv2-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
│       ├── atlas-dashboardv2-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
│       ├── classes
│       ├── dist
│       ├── gruntfile.js
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       ├── node
│       ├── node_modules
│       ├── package-lock.json
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── rat.txt
│       └── test-classes
├── dashboardv3
│   ├── gruntfile.js
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── ieerror.html
│   │   ├── img
│   │   ├── index.html.tpl
│   │   └── js
│   └── target
│       ├── atlas-dashboardv3-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
│       ├── atlas-dashboardv3-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
│       ├── classes
│       ├── dist
│       ├── gruntfile.js
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       ├── node
│       ├── node_modules
│       ├── package-lock.json
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── rat.txt
│       └── test-classes
├── dev-support
│   ├── atlas-docker
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── Dockerfile.atlas
│   │   ├── Dockerfile.atlas-base
│   │   ├── Dockerfile.atlas-build
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── data
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   ├── docker-compose.atlas-base.yml
│   │   ├── docker-compose.atlas-build.yml
│   │   ├── docker-compose.atlas.yml
│   │   ├── patches
│   │   └── scripts
│   ├── atlas-scripts
│   │   ├── README.txt
│   │   ├── admin_status.sh
│   │   ├── classificationdef_get.sh
│   │   ├── entity_classification_bulk.sh
│   │   ├── entity_classifications_add.sh
│   │   ├── entity_classifications_delete.sh
│   │   ├── entity_classifications_update.sh
│   │   ├── entity_create.sh
│   │   ├── entity_delete_by_guid.sh
│   │   ├── entity_get_by_guid.sh
│   │   ├── entity_get_by_type_and_unique_attr.sh
│   │   ├── entity_update.sh
│   │   ├── entity_update_by_type_and_unique_attr.sh
│   │   ├── entitydef_get.sh
│   │   ├── enumdef_get.sh
│   │   ├── env_atlas.sh
│   │   ├── export_entity_by_guid.sh
│   │   ├── export_entity_by_type_and_attr.sh
│   │   ├── import_zip.sh
│   │   ├── sample-data
│   │   ├── search_basic.sh
│   │   ├── search_basic_with_attribute_filters.sh
│   │   ├── search_dsl.sh
│   │   ├── structdef_get.sh
│   │   ├── typedefs_create.sh
│   │   ├── typedefs_delete.sh
│   │   ├── typedefs_get.sh
│   │   └── typedefs_update.sh
│   ├── findbugsIncludeFile.xml
│   ├── smart-apply-patch.sh
│   └── test-patch.sh
├── distro
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   ├── conf
│   │   ├── data
│   │   ├── logs
│   │   ├── main
│   │   ├── server
│   │   └── test
│   └── target
│       ├── META-INF
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-atlas-index-repair.zip
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-classification-updater.zip
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-falcon-hook.tar.gz
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hbase-hook.tar.gz
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-hive-hook.tar.gz
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-impala-hook.tar.gz
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-kafka-hook.tar.gz
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-server.tar.gz
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.tar.gz
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-sqoop-hook.tar.gz
│       ├── apache-atlas-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-storm-hook.tar.gz
│       ├── archive-tmp
│       ├── atlas-distro-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       ├── bin
│       ├── conf
│       ├── data
│       ├── logs
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       ├── rat.txt
│       ├── server
│       └── test-classes
├── docs
│   ├── docz-lib
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├── docz
│   │   └── docz-core
│   ├── doczrc.js
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── documents
│   │   └── resources
│   ├── target
│   │   ├── atlas-docs-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│   │   ├── classes
│   │   ├── docz-lib
│   │   ├── doczrc.js
│   │   ├── maven-archiver
│   │   ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── rat.txt
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── test-classes
│   │   └── theme
│   └── theme
│       ├── components
│       ├── config.js
│       ├── index.js
│       ├── styles
│       └── utils
├── graphdb
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── graphdb-impls
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   └── target
│   ├── janus
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── readme.txt
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── janus-hbase2
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── readme.txt
│   └── target
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       └── rat.txt
├── intg
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   └── test
│   └── target
│       ├── atlas-intg-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
│       ├── atlas-intg-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       ├── classes
│       ├── generated-sources
│       ├── generated-test-sources
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       ├── maven-status
│       ├── rat.txt
│       └── test-classes
├── notification
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   └── test
│   └── target
│       ├── atlas-notification-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       ├── classes
│       ├── dependency
│       ├── generated-sources
│       ├── generated-test-sources
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       ├── maven-status
│       ├── rat.txt
│       └── test-classes
├── plugin-classloader
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   └── test
│   └── target
│       ├── atlas-plugin-classloader-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       ├── classes
│       ├── generated-sources
│       ├── generated-test-sources
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       ├── maven-status
│       ├── rat.txt
│       └── test-classes
├── pom.xml
├── release-build.xml
├── release-log.txt
├── repository
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   └── test
│   └── target
│       ├── atlas-repository-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
│       ├── atlas-repository-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       ├── classes
│       ├── generated-sources
│       ├── generated-test-sources
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       ├── maven-status
│       ├── rat.txt
│       ├── solr
│       └── test-classes
├── server-api
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   └── target
│       ├── atlas-server-api-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       ├── classes
│       ├── generated-sources
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       ├── maven-status
│       ├── rat.txt
│       └── test-classes
├── target
│   ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│   │   └── META-INF
│   └── rat.txt
├── test-tools
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   └── target
│       ├── atlas-testtools-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
│       ├── classes
│       ├── generated-sources
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
│       ├── maven-status
│       ├── rat.txt
│       └── test-classes
├── tools
│   ├── atlas-index-repair
│   │   ├── README
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── atlas-migration-exporter
│   │   ├── README
│   │   ├── atlas-log4j.xml
│   │   └── atlas_migration_export.py
│   └── classification-updater
│       ├── pom.xml
│       ├── src
│       └── target
└── webapp
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
    │   ├── main
    │   └── test
    └── target
        ├── api
        ├── atlas-webapp-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        ├── atlas-webapp-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar
        ├── atlas-webapp-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
        ├── atlas.keystore
        ├── classes
        ├── enunciate
        ├── generated-sources
        ├── generated-test-sources
        ├── maven-archiver
        ├── maven-shared-archive-resources
        ├── maven-status
        ├── models
        ├── rat.txt
        ├── solr
        ├── test-classes
        └── war
```

Whenever I want to run `atlas_start.py` file, I faced to following logs:

```
/bigdata/atlas/distro/src/conf/atlas-env.sh: line 59: MANAGE_LOCAL_HBASE=${hbase.embedded}: bad substitution
/bigdata/atlas/distro/src/conf/atlas-env.sh: line 62: MANAGE_LOCAL_SOLR=${solr.embedded}: bad substitution
/bigdata/atlas/distro/src/conf/atlas-env.sh: line 65: MANAGE_EMBEDDED_CASSANDRA=${cassandra.embedded}: bad substitution
/bigdata/atlas/distro/src/conf/atlas-env.sh: line 68: MANAGE_LOCAL_ELASTICSEARCH=${elasticsearch.managed}: bad substitution
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /bigdata/atlas/distro/src/server/webapp/atlas.war (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:407)
    at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1681)
The Server is no longer running with pid 29164
starting atlas on host localhost
starting atlas on port 21000
..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Apache Atlas Server started!!!
```

here is the curl:

```
curl -u username:password http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/v2/types/typedefs/headers
```

**error**:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 21000: Connection refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with Apache Atlas for a while, I found `3.0.0 Snapshot` version very buggy! Therefore I have decided to build and install `Apache Atlas 2.1.0 RC3`.

**Prerequisite:**

Make sure you have installed java on your machine. In case it is not installed on your computer, you can install it using the following command in Linux:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre`

Then `JAVA_HOME` should be set:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

**Building:**

1. Download Apache Atlas 2.1.0-rc3:

```
wget https://github.com/apache/atlas/archive/refs/tags/release-2.1.0-rc3.tar.gz
```

2. Unpack it:

```
 tar -xzvf release-2.1.0-rc3.tar.gz
```

3. Set environment variables:

```
export MANAGE_LOCAL_HBASE=true
export MANAGE_LOCAL_SOLR=true
```

4. Execute:

```
mvn clean -DskipTests install
mvn clean -DskipTests package -Pdist,embedded-hbase-solr
```

5. Change the directory to distro/target and unpack the server tar file:

```
cd distro/target
tar -xzvf apache-atlas-2.1.0-server.tar.gz
```

6. Change the directory to apache-atlas-2.1.0-server and run execute atlas_start.py script:

```
cd apache-atlas-2.1.0-server
bin/atlas_start.py
```

**Important Tip 1:** In official documentation it is said to change directory to apache-atlas-2.1.0, not apache-atlas-2.1.0-server. I have tried it but it doesn't work.

**Important Tip 2:** The following log doesn't mean that Apache Atlas is currently running!

```
 configured for local hbase.
hbase started.
configured for local solr.
solr started.
setting up solr collections…
starting atlas on host localhost
starting atlas on port 21000
Apache Atlas Server started!!
```

To ensure that it is working properly or not, check the application.log in logs directory. If everything would be OK, it takes about 10 minutes to run without any error.

**Brief screenshot of logs/application.log:**
[image: application.log apache atlas]

```
**Check the function:**

> curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:21000/api/atlas/admin/version                                                                                                                                 

{"Description":"Metadata Management and Data Governance Platform over Hadoop","Revision":"release","Version":"2.1.0","Name":"apache-atlas"}%
```

or

http://localhost:21000 should look-like the following picture:
[image: Apache Atlas]

---

I want to thank Mark Chesnavsky helping me to resolve this issue. If you have any other issue you can check [his post](https://mchesnavsky.tech/apache-atlas-building-installing/).